# Instegram API call (acces_token not working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

i am trying to fetch Instagram pictures with API call in reactjs but i am getting an error message like code: 400
error_message: "The access_token provided is invalid."
error_type: "OAuthAccessTokenException"

What could be the problem here?

here is my code:

function ImageSlider() {

```
const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=IGQVJXQjBmWXprMmhIOU9vWU1VTTJiMmpSeC1CTFh6M2d0MDRpOTYtQi1pT2JKMC1BWjNrd0VYU1EyUXhjM1NWTHpJeENDT05HT2tkMTgyNWpfYmpXWndGa1FuMzZA0OUhBTW5peUw0NVBzD';
    fetch(url).then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(resp=>console.log(resp))
},[]); 
return (
    <div>
        {
           photo.map((photos, key) => {
            return (
              <div key={photos.id}>
                <img src={photos.images.standard_resolution.url} alt={photos.caption}/>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }          
    </div>
);
```

}

export default ImageSlider;

Comment: As It is mentioned in the error that the access token is invalid, You should generate a new access token (mentioned in the url) right after the access_token.

Comment: i have done that but still geting the same error.